# Update bootstrapper end instalation MSI but show 60/70% on progress bar

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I create my instalator Wix with msi and bootstrapper.
I am do test for update my program. And trying install new version. I want always use bootstrapper. I don't know if this was always the case, but I did some tweaks and added a progress bar to the bootstrapper for MSI installations. And it turns out that when updating, this bar stops at 60/70% and after closing MSI a new bootstrapper window appears. Closing the window a few times causes the progress bar in the first window jump to 100% and I can close the window.

I dont have idea why it happen.

I check logs and in both cases last line looks like:

> Applying execute package: Installer, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{9428A5CF-824D-42D0-ABF7-BC69D4B8FEE7}v1.0.26.40\EkInstaller.Elements.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" CONFIGFILELOCATION="C:\svn\122\dotNet\products\3_ek-graf-pre-v2\trunk\src\Ek.Installer\Ek.Installer.Bootstrapper\bin\Debug"'

And besides this lines I dont show differents in logs:

> [4EDC:2970][2020-07-23T08:54:34]i102: Detected related bundle:
> {2e954545-621e-4062-a306-99197563c483}, type: Upgrade, scope:
> PerMachine, version: 1.0.24.39, operation: MajorUpgrade
>
> [4EDC:2970][2020-07-23T08:54:34]i102: Detected related bundle:
> {770a1869-f4b5-4307-b05f-1f8be006757b}, type: Upgrade, scope:
> PerMachine, version: 1.0.23.39, operation: MajorUpgrade
>
> [4EDC:2970][2020-07-23T08:54:34]i102: Detected related bundle:
> {ff8d8a34-989d-4fb9-9aa7-2ab0440f514d}, type: Upgrade, scope:
> PerMachine, version: 1.0.25.39, operation: MajorUpgrade
>
> [4EDC:2970][2020-07-23T08:54:34]i103: Detected related package:
> {D512899C-F7CC-412C-9110-54CDE5BB2741}, scope: PerMachine, version:
> 1.0.25.40, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade

Probably first three are for NetFramework, Sql and SSMS which install bootstrapper and last is for my MSI.

I was trying change InstallerVersion in Package and Schedule in MajorUpgrade.

The installer is very complex, I can't make all the code available. Maybe someone knows the reasons for this behavior and can direct me to why it is.

Noticed when MSI progress bar status = "Delete Files" in then progress bar bootstrapper stop.

Edit:

It spawn additional window bootstrapper for event previous version bootstrapper.
If i dont change version bootstrapper it dont spawn dialog and it goes to 100% normally when updating msi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a wix bug. For each subsequent bootstrapper version installed, new bootstrapper windows appear when the MSI window is closed. You can fix it by following through change UpgradeCode for each new version Bundle. If you additionally set DisableModify = "yes" DisableRemove = "yes" then there will be no additional bootstrapper instances in add / remove program.